# SSMS auto correcting datepart in view designer

Tags: sql-server, view, ssms

Super annoying fringe case I have run into.

In a view, I have a table that has a column called 'Year', which is an integer.
And in this view, I am trying to filter in relation to last year, so I use the following snippet.

```
WHERE Jobs.Year > YEAR(DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))
```

But ssms, in all it's infinite wisdom, thinks it's being helpful and replaces in datepart year into the Year column.

```
WHERE dbo.Jobs.Year > YEAR(DATEADD(dbo.Jobs.Year, - 1, GETDATE()))
```

Is there anyway to escape this behavior?

EDIT:
This is on SSMS 2014, it seems this issue is not present on some later versions.

Comment: Year is SQL keyword, for your where try this  WHERE Jobs.[Year] = YEAR(DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))

Comment: Generally it's bad practice to name columns after key and reserved words. Thus (and not attempting to be rude at all), the problem is the column using a keyword; and thus intellisense is therefore using your column instead of the keyword due to the conflict. Personally, if you can, I'd try changing the name of your column(s) to not use key and reserved words.

Comment: Yes I 100% agree using a reserved word is the real problem here, not my handiwork unfortunately. Can't be changed.
@Brad Escaping the column dosnt do anything, it's the date part inside the DATEADD that would need to be escaped in someway. [year] dosnt work either.

Comment: if I run this select , what you are doing in your where, I get 2017 returned:   SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))  so this is working fine

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using?  I can enter `> YEAR(DATEADD(Year, - 1, GETDATE()))` into the Filter column in the designer just fine without it automatically converting it to a table column name.  I'm using SSMS 2017 (v17.6)

Comment: @Brad Yes the query works fine, it's that when I enter it into ssms view editor it 'auto corrects' it to the column.
I am on 2014, so I guess they fixed it later. Bummer.

Comment: you can use yy instead of the word year:
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()))

Comment: @Brad Wow, exactly what I was looking for. If you want to answer with that I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound, glad I could help, and posted as answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving from my comment to here.

You are having issues with the word "YEAR" in your datepart as it is a reserved word.  You can change to get the same results that from:

```
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()))
```

to:

```
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()))
```

For reference here is a list of all the valid dateparts:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datepart.asp